# find an item inside a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a list of dictionaries.
each dict in the list has 3 elements.
Name, id and status.

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id':1, 'name':'Alice', 'status':0},{'id':2, 'name':'Bob', 'status':0},{'id':3, 'name':'Robert', 'status':1}]
```

so I get:

```
In[20]: print list_of_dicts
Out[20]: 
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Alice', 'status': 0},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob', 'status': 0},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'Robert', 'status': 1}]
```

If i recieve a name, how can I get its status without iterating on the list?

 e.g. I get 'Robert' and I want to output 1.
 thank you.

Comment: You can't unless you convert your initial `lod` into a different data structure, which itself will require an iteration. That might still be preferrable if you have to query multiple names.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it without iterating on the list. If you have to do the search many times it might be worth inverting the data structure into `{'Alice': 0, 'Bob': 0, 'Robert': 1}`. Then you only iterate once.

Comment: @BoarGules Agreed. If there are duplicate names, you might have to include `id` in the query/keys.

Comment: maybe you should use dict of dicts (instead of list of dicts) and use {name}_{id} as key

Comment: I see, so if I have to iterate, how would you recommend to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found you have to iterate (unless you are able to change your data structure to an enclosing dict) why don't you just do it?

```
>>> [d['status'] for d in list_of_dicts if d['name']=='Robert']
[1]
```

Despite this, I recommend considering a map type (like dict) every time you see some 'id' field in a proposed data structure. If it's there you probably want to use it for general identification, instead of carrying dicts around. They can be used for relations also, and transfer easily into a relational database if you need it later.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to do this without iteration.

However, but you can transform you dictionary into a different data structure, such as a dictionary where names are the keys:

```
new_dict = {person["name"]: {k: v for k, v in person.items() if k != "name"} for person in list_of_dicts}
```

Then you can get the status like so:

```
new_dict["Robert"]["status"]
# 1
```

Additionally, as [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836295/find-an-item-inside-a-list-of-dictionaries/53836504?noredirect=1#comment94523212_53836504) mentions in the comments, you can keep the internal dictionary the same:

```
{person["name"]: person for person in list_of_dicts}
```

The only issue with the above approaches is that it can't handle multiple names. You can instead add the unique id into the key to differentiate between names:

```
new_dict = {(person["name"], person["id"]): person["status"] for person in list_of_dicts}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
new_dict["Robert", 3]
# 1
```

Even though it takes extra computation(only once) to create these data structures, the lookups afterwards will be O(1), instead of iterating the list every time when you want to search a name.

Comment: I would suggest just `{person["name"]: person for person in list_of_dicts}`, so the internal dicts are still in the same format (and indeed `new_dict.values()` is pretty much the same as `list_of_dicts`, at least for newer versions of Python), for compatibility with other parts of the code.

Answer (score 4):

for example you can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
list_of_dicts = [{'id':1, 'name':'Alice', 'status':0},{'id':2, 'name':'Bob', 'status':0},{'id':3, 'name':'Robert', 'status':1}]

a = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
a.loc[a['name'] == 'Robert']
```

and play with dataframes its very fast because write on c++ and easy (like sql queries)

Comment: This is what I would recommend. To add: the problem can be simplified using a custom class. Thankfully, Pandas has provided such a class via `pd.DataFrame` so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do what you ask without iterating through the dictionary:
Best case, you'll find someone that suggests you a method that hides the iteration.

If what really concerns you is the speed, you may break your iteration as soon as you find the first valid result:

```
for iteration, elements in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
    if elements['name'] == "Robert":
        print "Elements id: ", elements['id']
        break
print "Iterations: ", iteration

# OUTPUT: Elements id: 3, Iterations: 1
```

Note that numbers of iteration may vary, since dictionaries are not indexed, and if you have more `"Roberts"`, only for one the `"id"` will be printed

Answer (score 2):

Your `list_of_dicts`  cannot be reached without a loop so for your desire your list should be modified a little like ***1 dict and many lists*** in it:

```
list_of_dicts_modified = {'name':['Alice', 'Bob', 'Robert'],'id':[1, 2, 3], 'status': [0, 0, 1]}
index = list_of_dicts_modified['name'].index(input().strip())
print('Name: {0} ID: {1} Status: {2}'.format(list_of_dicts_modified['name'][index], list_of_dicts_modified['id'][index], list_of_dicts_modified['status'][index]))
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
Alice
Name: Alice ID: 1 Status: 0
```